# produce vector output from a dask array

Tags: python, geospatial, dask, rasterio

I have a large dask array (`labeled_arr`) that is actually a labeled raster image (dtype is int64). I want to use rasterio to turn the labeled regions into polygons and combine them into a single list of polygons (or geoseries with just a geometry column). This is a straightforward task on a single array, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell dask that I want it to do this operation on each chunk and return something that is not an array.

function to apply to each chunk:

```
def get_polys(labeled_blocks):
    polys = list(poly[0]['coordinates'][0] for poly in rasterio.features.shapes(
                                labeled_blocks.astype('int32'), transform=trans))[:-1]
    # Note: rasterio.features.shapes returns an iterator, hence the conversion to a list here
    return polys
```

line of code trying to get dask to do this:

```
test_polygons = da.blockwise(get_polys, '', labeled_arr, 'ij')
test_polygons.compute()
```

where `labeled_arr` is the input chunked dask array.

Running as is returns an error saying I have to specify a dtype for `da.blockwise`. Specifying a dtype returns an AttributeError since the output list type does not have a dtype attribute. I discovered the `meta` keyword, but still have been unable to get the right syntax to turn my output into a Series or list.

I'm not attached to the above approach, but my overarching goal is: take a labeled, chunked dask dataarray (which does not all fit in memory), extract a list based on computations for each chunk, and generate a concatenated list (or pandas data object) with the outputs from all the chunks in my original chunked array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da

# we expect to see 4 blocks here
test_array = da.random.random((4, 4), chunks=(2, 2))

@dask.delayed
def my_func(block):
    # do something fancy
    return list(block)

results = dask.compute([my_func(x) for x in test_array.to_delayed().ravel()])
```

As you noted, the problem is that `list` has no `dtype`. A way around this would be to convert the `list` into a `np.array`, but I'm not sure if this will work with all `geometry` objects (it should be OK for `Points`, but polygons might be problematic due to varying length). Since you are not interested in forcing these geometries into an array, it's best to treat individual blocks as `delayed` objects feeding them into your function one at a time (but scaled across workers/processes).

Comment: Thanks @SultanOrazbayev! This approach worked great, though I did end up having to unnest a tuple of length one containing some nested lists. Unfortunately I ran into issues with the geospatial component, because I was trying to reattach coordinates in `my_func`, but I only have a transform computed for my entire dataset, not each dask chunk. I ended up with a solution modified from my initial post:

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I ended up with initially, though it still requires a lot of RAM given the concatenate=True kwarg.

```
poss_list = []
def get_polys(labeled_blocks):
    polys = list(poly[0]['coordinates'][0] for poly in rasterio.features.shapes(
                        labeled_blocks.astype('int32'), transform=trans))[:-1]
    poss_list.append(polys)
        
da.blockwise(get_bergs, '', labeled_arr, 'ij', 
                meta=pd.DataFrame({'c':[]}), concatenate=True).compute()
```

If I'm interpreting correctly, this doesn't feed the chunks into my function across workers/processes though (which it seems I can get away with for now).

**Update - improved answer using dask.delayed, building on the accepted answer by @SultanOrazbayev**

```
import dask
# onedem = original_xarray_dataarray
poss_list = []

@dask.delayed
def get_bergs(labeled_blocks, pointer, chunk0, chunk1):
            
    # Note: I'm using this in a CRS (polar stereo) with negative y coordinates - it hasn't been tested for other CRSs
    def getpx(chunkid, chunksz):
       amin = chunkid[0] * chunksz[0][0]
       amax = amin + chunksz[0][0]
       bmin = chunkid[1] * chunksz[1][0]
       bmax = bmin + chunksz[1][0]
       return (amin, amax, bmin, bmax)

    # order of all inputs (and outputs) should be y, x when axis order is used
    chunksz = (onedem.chunks['y'], onedem.chunks['x'])
    ymini, ymaxi, xmini, xmaxi = getpx((chunk0, chunk1), chunksz) 

    # use rasterio Windows and rioxarray to construct transform
    # https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#window-transforms
    chwindow = rasterio.windows.Window(xmini, ymini, xmaxi-xmini, ymaxi-ymini) #.from_slices[ymini, ymaxi],[xmini, xmaxi])
    trans = onedem.rio.isel_window(chwindow).rio.transform(recalc=True)

    return list(poly[0]['coordinates'][0] for poly in rasterio.features.shapes(labeled_blocks.astype('int32'), transform=trans))[:-1]

        
for __, obj in enumerate(labeled_arr.to_delayed()):
   for bl in obj:
      piece = dask.delayed(get_bergs)(bl, *bl.key)
      poss_list.append(piece)
        
poss_list = dask.compute(*poss_list)
        
# unnest the list of polygons returned by using dask to polygonize
concat_list = [item for sublist in poss_list for item in sublist if len(item)!=0]
```

Comment: What happens here is you are modifying `poss_list`, which is external to the `get_polys`, so it can't happen in parallel, which constrains dask.

Comment: Check section 'Avoid global state' in the best practices for this specific case: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll look into it and see if I can come up with a better practices solution that gets my geospatial info in the correctly!

Comment: One somewhat hacky way is to store this info in a file, and ask workers to load the file when necessary.

Comment: Yeah - I'm thinking that long term it would be cool to try and build some of this chunk-wise geospatial handling into rioxarray and related tools too. But your separate file solution would make a good stopgap. I suspect I could also generate chunk-wise transforms and keep them in my Xarray dataset containing the dask arrays.

Comment: If I can help, feel free to ping me on GitHub.

Comment: I tried to implement the dask.delayed approach, but I've been struggling to figure out how to get the function (`my_func()` in the accepted answer) to identify which chunk it is on so that I can also feed it a corresponding geotransform. Neither the `block_id` nor `block_info` kwargs that are available for `map_blocks` and `blockwise` seem to be available, and if I try to use either of those functions I'm back at the original issue of having a non-array function return.

Comment: Would it work for you if you knew the sequential order of each block? If yes, then you can use `enumerate` on the delayed objects, like this: `[my_func(x, n) for n, x in enumerate(test_array.to_delayed().ravel())]`

Comment: If you really need the block number/id, then you could also remove `.ravel()` in the comment above, that will generate a list of lists, so you can iterate over them with appropriate enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, @SultanOrazbayev! I've puzzled through using your suggestions and come up with a way to compute a per-chunk geotransform to apply to each raster chunk so that it produces vectors (polygons) in the correct crs (I'm posting the answer separately).

Comment: The last three lines of the code should be outside the loop, right? Or maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Nice catch - the formatting got messed up when I copy-pasted the code and I missed fixing those indents! They should be all set now.